# Laravel strange routing behavior- routing issue

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, routes

In my application, when user clicks a tag in tag-cloud, he the laravel returns the result with db for that tag cloud.
Now I have a strange problem.

Say I clicked lorem tag - then the posts with lorem tag are shown.

```
/public/tag/lorem
```

But after this, when I try to navigate via the menu, say click on home or blog,
it goes to

```
/public/tag/home.html
/public/tag/blog.html
```

Why is this?
Here are my routes

```
Route::get('/blog/tags/{any?}', array('uses'=>'BCr@sortTags', 'as'=>'tags'));
```

Can somebody please guide.

Comment: How did you code your anchor link in navigation? Can you share code of that part? I believe if you use something like `"URL::to("/")."/home";` your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is expected as because when you are at `tag/lorem` and then you click on blog link which is referred to `blog.html` it just replace `lorem` with blog.html. If you really want to correct the link then you should change your link of home and blog with its absolute link something like `/public/blog.html`(not only `blog.html`) or you can also link to its route's name. Try this. Best of luck.